Running gradle task, assemble debug failed?
I just ran my flutter appin Android Studio for the first time and it showed me an error
E:\projects\demo>flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'E:\projects\demo\android\settings.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader', version: '1.0.0']
> Could not find implementation class 'FlutterAppPluginLoaderPlugin' for plugin 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader' specified in jar:file:/C:/Users/hmtah/.gradle/caches/jars-9/e6cddf9d04a43b46087935310ebe833f/gradle-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader.properties.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             68.2s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


I ran the command flutter clean and flutter pub get following flutter run but still it shows the same error. I expected my app to run but it fails again and again.
